# How concerned should I be? Foundation wall moisture post-rainstorm

Tags: foundation

While working on a skim coating project, I noticed that the bottom of the drywall felt unusually weak. After deciding to investigate further, I was surprised to discover wet foundation walls behind it. You can see the extent of the moisture in this photo

https://share.icloud.com/photos/05dCCq2PiRN39DbmPt4HRg9PA.

[image: water]
Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? What’s the best course of action to remedy this? I’m wondering if waterproofing is the way to go, or if there are other solutions I should consider.

Any advice or experiences you can share would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Water proofing foundations start on the outside.  Might just need to add a water proof membrane(tar or newer stuff) to the outside of the walls, or need drainage and/or proper grading of the ground.  Inside water proofing is usually just a temporary fix, more water resistance than proofing.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear you have absolutely no water barrier on the outside wall.

This is going to be a short and long therm problem.

There are few ways to remedy that, so get on with it.